# login.php No esta respondiendo

Tags: php, html, sql

Saludos a todos tengo el siguiente código en un archivo login.php el cual recibe un POST del index, probé el POST con un echo en el login y se esta enviando y recibiendo desde el index, pero el login.php se queda en blanco y no me redirige a ninguna parte ni me da algún mensaje. El fin del código es que busque en 3 tablas a ver donde se encuentra el usuario

````
<?php include 'includes/head-main.php'; ?>
<?php
require('config.php');

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
            // El usuario ha ingresado credenciales válidas
            header('Location: admin_dashboard.php');
            exit();
        } else {
            // El usuario ha ingresado credenciales inválidas
            echo "Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos.";
    }
}
?>```
````

Answer (score 1):

cuando usas header no debe de haber nada que escape al navegador antes de esta funcion.

prueba cambiar esto

```
<?php include 'includes/head-main.php'; ?>
<?php
require('config.php');
```

por esto

```
<?php include 'includes/head-main.php';
    require('config.php');
```

si aun asi no funciona prueba escribir algo y si hay aun que sea un espacio en la salida es por que debes buscarlo y eliminiarlo

```
<?php include 'includes/head-main.php';
    require('config.php');
    die("texto");
```

Comment: Lo que hice fue poner el head-main al final del código y funcionó

Comment: eso quiere decir que tienes un problema en head-main, lo que hiciste fue saltar el problema, pero puede traer otras consecuencias si antes del include hay dependencias de alguna variable interna de ese archivo.